# Cómo completar una condicional usando javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

Estoy buscando completar una condicional, exactamente hay que ubicar lo que se ingrese en el input entre las comillas simples, usando javascript.

¿Cómo hacerlo?

```css
.cond-content{
display: flex;
}
.cond-content > input{
width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="cond-content">
<input type="text" placeholder="Completa la condicional"/>
<button>Completar</button>
</div>


<b:if cond="data:blog.pageType == 'Aquí va el texto del input entre comillas'"></b:if>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para ubicar texto entre los signos `'` y `'` podrías usar el método `split` que crea un array cortando el contenido donde se encuentra los signos de `'`.

```css
.cond-content{
display: flex;
}
.cond-content > input{
width: 100%;
}

em {
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #b2b2b2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cond-content">
<input onkeyup="validar(this)" type="text" id="input" placeholder="Completa la condicional"/ value="hola 'soy' el nuevo 'señor' de los 'anillos'">
<button onclick="validar()">Completar</button>
</div>
<br>
<div id="encontro"></div>

<b:if cond="data:blog.pageType == 'Aquí va el texto del input entre comillas'"></b:if>

<script>
   function validar(element){
      let input = $('#input').val()
      if( element !== undefined && element !== null ){
        input = $(element).val()
      }
      let condicionales = new Array();
      let mod = 3;
      let condIndex = 1;
      let elsplit = input.split("'");
      if(elsplit.length >= mod ){
        condicionales = new Array();
        while(condIndex < elsplit.length ){
          condicionales.push(elsplit[condIndex])
          condIndex += 2;
        }
      }
      $('#encontro')[0].innerHTML = '';
      condicionales.reverse().forEach((item)=>{
        $('#encontro').prepend("<em>'"+item+"'</em>")
      })
   }
  
</script>
```